# how to include part of a map extent in layout view

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap

I have a map of Scotland and within the map layout I'd like to include Shetland within a box at the top so that I don't have to minimise the full extent of the map - I was wondering what the best way to do this would be. Previously i created a duplicate layer in the data view and zoomed it to only fit in Shetland in the layout view but this seemed a clunky way of doing this? Anyone have any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to add another map view over another area you would use another [data frame](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//006600000004000000) (Insert > Data Frame). Learn [here](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s900000007000000) how to work with multiple data frames in page layout.

You can switch between data frames in Table of Contents and zoom as required. In Layout view, you can move data frames as needed.

Comment: Thanks Alex - I did as you described and is exactly what I was looking for but how do I know when sizing the additional data frame in layout view that they have the same scale? Thanks again

Comment: In addition to this answer, have a look at [extent indicators](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00s900000005000000)!

Comment: @user2932466, frankly speaking I don't know. I would just jump between them and set the scale manually to be what I want.

Comment: Recalled this night that you can add a scale text/bar (Insert menu) for each data frame so you can see the scale changing as you zoom in/out in each data frame.